# struct termios unknown behavior in C

Tags: c

With this code, when I take input, the input does not appear, when I comment it out it appears, what is this code doing below,

```
struct termios origConfig;
tcgetattr(0, &origConfig);
struct termios newConfig = origConfig;
newConfig.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO);
newConfig.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
newConfig.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &newConfig);
```

Comment: can you add the structure termois declaration and a small code that would reproduce the problem ?

Comment: @Pradheep Unnecessary to add the declaration, it's a standard header.

Comment: @Pradheep the structure is in termios.h . http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newConfig.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO);
```

will reset the echo and canonical-input flags. If you don't want to reset the echo flag (but keep everything else), just use:

```
newConfig.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
```

altough you may also want to examine how the canonical-input flag works as well. For example, see the [Linux termios man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios).

In any case, it may be unwise to use one without the other since one of the major use cases on non-canonical input is things like editors, where you *don't* want characters echoed.

Non-caconical input gives you each character as it's typed (rather than an entire line when you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>), ideal for editors. If your editor needs to handle things like <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> to move forward one word, you probably don't want it banging the `^W` in the middle of your screen display.

Instead, you'd want it to leave the output up to the program, rather than the terminal interface. Non-canonical, non-echo terminal I/O gives you much more power over the interface.

Answer (score 0):

The `tcsetattr()` function controls the behavior of the user terminal. In this particular case, the code clears the `ECHO` flag in the control structure (`newConfig.c_lflag &= ~ECHO` does that), so what the user types isn't echoed back.

Comment: @H2C03 how can I fix it while keeping that code?

Comment: :-O You are not the real H2CO3, he has Penguin on his DisplayPicture :-P

Comment: Er... that's the whole point of this code. If you don't want to turn off input echoing, don't run this!

Comment: @RichardMckenna Why do you need this code to be in? (Also, if line XXX causes the problem, then you generally fix it by removing line XXX...)